# JMeter with OpenID Connect authentication

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, openid-connect, blazemeter

I'm trying to create performance testing with JMeter to our web application which uses OpenID Connect for authentication.

I have used the following guide: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/openid-connect-how-to-load-test-with-jmeter, but seemed not to work on what I am doing. I have recorded steps through BlazeMeter.

May I ask if someone can help me give sample or instructions how to use OpenID Connect auth in JMeter please.

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to replay the recorded test OpenID assumes **correlation** - the process of extracting dynamic parameters from the response using [JMeter PostProcessors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), saving them into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and replacing hard-coded recorded values with the aforementioned variables.

No one can provide you "help" as there are too many possible providers and too many configuration options even given single provider.

General recommendation is:

1. Record your test plan 2 times. Make sure to have [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener under the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder
2. Inspect recorded request details and identify the values which are dynamic
3. Configure JMeter to extract dynamic values from the response and substitute the request parameters which are different
4. Carefully inspect [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) elements as dynamic values might also live there
5. Add  [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan
6. You might also find [How to Load Test OpenId Secured Websites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-openid-secured-websites)
   guide easier to read/understand.